# pandas: df.apply() behind-the-scene calculation with df.groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am very confused about how `df.apply()` work. Here is one of the issues I have:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips['tip_pct'] = tips['tip'] / tips['total_bill']

tips.head()

       total_bill   tip smoker  day    time  size   tip_pct
0       16.99  1.01     No  Sun  Dinner     2  0.059447
1       10.34  1.66     No  Sun  Dinner     3  0.160542
2       21.01  3.50     No  Sun  Dinner     3  0.166587
3       23.68  3.31     No  Sun  Dinner     2  0.139780
4       24.59  3.61     No  Sun  Dinner     4  0.146808
```

I am trying to sort `tips` by `tips['tip_pct']` column. I can apply `sort_values` directly.

```
In [153]: tips.sort_values(by='tip_pct').head()
Out[153]: 
     total_bill   tip smoker  day    time  size   tip_pct
237       32.83  1.17    Yes  Sat  Dinner     2  0.035638
102       44.30  2.50    Yes  Sat  Dinner     3  0.056433
57        26.41  1.50     No  Sat  Dinner     2  0.056797
0         16.99  1.01     No  Sun  Dinner     2  0.059447
187       30.46  2.00    Yes  Sun  Dinner     5  0.065660
```

Now, I am trying to group this data frame by `smoker` column first, and sort by `tip_pct` column.

```
In [156]: tips.groupby('smoker').apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='tip_pct')).head()
Out[156]: 
            total_bill   tip smoker   day    time  size   tip_pct
smoker                                                           
No     57        26.41  1.50     No   Sat  Dinner     2  0.056797
       0         16.99  1.01     No   Sun  Dinner     2  0.059447
       48        28.55  2.05     No   Sun  Dinner     3  0.071804
       146       18.64  1.36     No  Thur   Lunch     3  0.072961
       130       19.08  1.50     No  Thur   Lunch     2  0.078616
```

I tried to understand how does `groupby` and `apply` work together, so I tried the following, but it failed.

```
In [157]: for name, group in tips.groupby('smoker'):
     ...:     group.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='tip_pct'))
     ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-5b5096eaa4d6> in <module>()
      1 for name, group in tips.groupby('smoker'):
----> 2     group.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='tip_pct'))
      3 

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4260                         f, axis,
   4261                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4262                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4263             else:
   4264                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4356             try:
   4357                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4358                     results[i] = func(v)
   4359                     keys.append(v.name)
   4360             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-157-5b5096eaa4d6> in <lambda>(x)
      1 for name, group in tips.groupby('smoker'):
----> 2     group.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='tip_pct'))
      3 

TypeError: ("sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'", 'occurred at index total_bill')
```

My understanding the reason of the failure is because `apply()` function tries to `sort_value` on each column, so `by` doesn't apply on `series.sort_values()`. However, I don't understant why `groupby` doesn't have any issues. per my understanding, `groupby` just split the dataset, so it is still several smaller data frame, which will have issues like the above when applying `sort_values()`.

Can anyone explain why `groupby` and `apply(sort_values)` doesn't have any issues that is caused by directly apply `sort_values` to original data frame?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With for loop , you will see the `group` here is the data frame split by the group key 

   ` for name, group in df.groupby('smoker'):
        print(group.sort_values(by='tip_pct'))`

Comment: @Wen, I understand your method will work, but I don't understand is why `groupby` the dataset first and then `apply(sort_values)` won't have any issues. Do you know the reason?

Comment: apply is kind of for loop so after doing one for loop another one for loop has been added the will failed

Comment: @Wen, I understand your point. However, if I directly apply `tips.apply(sort_values)`, it will have the same issue. That's why I want to understand the behind-the-scenes calculation of `apply()` and `groupby()`. It seems that the smaller dataset created by `groupby()` won't have issues with `apply()` but the original dataset does.